# Empty set Velleman's exercises

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Doing an exercise from Velleman's 'How to prove it' I ended up thinking about exercise 2.3.8: Given that there are sets $ I=\{2,3\}, A_2=\{2,4\},A_3=\{3,6\},B_2=\{2,3\},B_3=\{3,4\}$. What is $(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)\cup(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i)$?

I proceeded as follows: $$(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)\cup(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i)=\{x|x \in\{\emptyset\} \lor x \in \{3\}\}. $$ Is it correct? The correct answer according to Velleman is $\{3\}$. Can it also be equal to  $\{\emptyset,3\}$?

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}\cup\{3\}=...$? I guess you mean $x\in\emptyset\lor x\in\{3\}$. Then $\emptyset\cup\{3\}=\{3\}$.

Comment: It could also be $\{3\}$ even as printed, if you mean the ordinal $3$ as defined in set theory

Comment: ok, seems like $\{x|x \in\{\emptyset\} \lor x \in \{3\}\} $ is wrong. I will edit the question in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than work with logic symbols, we can observe that:

\begin{align}
\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i\right) \cup \left(\bigcap_{i \in I} B_i\right) &= \left(A_2 \cap A_3\right) \cup \left(B_2 \cap B_3\right) \\
&= \varnothing \cup \{3\} \\
&= \{3\}.
\end{align}

In other words, because $\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$ is **not** $\{\varnothing\}$, you cannot do what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

$\{ \varnothing \}$ is **not** the empty set.

$\varnothing$ is the empty set $\{\}$.

$\{ \varnothing , 3 \} = \{ \{\} , 3 \}$ contains two objects, one is the empty set and the other is $3$.